# Creating Water distribution network using QGIS

Tags: qgis, network, distribution, water

Is it possible to create a water distribution network from an existing LineLayer and existing PointLayer (junctions)?

I want to create an distribution Network with:
selected starting location;
calculate volume/capacity trough pipes/lines based on demand from all buildings;

How can I create such a network?
pyqgis? plug-in? build-in processing?

Right now I achieved:

- building locations (red points)
- junctions in front of each building (green points)
- pipe connecting building and junction (purple line)
- minimum spanning tree of the distribution network.
  see image below:

How can i determine the flow trough the pipes based on the volume demand of each junction? A starting point is required for this but how do i assign a starting point?

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific what you're asking. Because currently the answer would be: Yes.

Comment: how can i achieve this?

Comment: By breaking down the whole process into smaller steps, ideally corresponding to known workflows and/or tools, then trying them, and when running into issues asking specific questions about that specific step/task.

Comment: I updated my topic